# Undefined reference to ev_timer_stop

Tags: c, linker-errors, undefined-reference

I'm getting an error undefined reference to `ev_timer_stop` when I try to run some code. I'm working on kubuntu.

I've  already installed libev-dev.

Here's the error:

```
client.cc:434: undefined reference to `ev_timer_stop'
/home/nithin/ngtcp2/examples/client.cc:435: undefined reference to `ev_timer_stop'
/home/nithin/ngtcp2/examples/client.cc:437: undefined reference to `ev_io_stop'
/home/nithin/ngtcp2/examples/client.cc:438: undefined reference to `ev_io_stop'
/home/nithin/ngtcp2/examples/client.cc:440: undefined reference to `ev_signal_stop'
```

Answer (score 0):

The linker does not know where to find `ev_timer_stop`.

You might like specifying by providing `-lev` to the compiler. Do this on the command line after (to the right) having specified the source/object files using stuff from `libev`.

Comment: I'm following the instructions on this site : https://blog.cloudflare.com/head-start-with-quic/. The command that gives the error is: make check.